# View statistics with colorbox module

Tags: views, nodes, javascript

So I'm building a community website for a local photography group and I'm trying to set up a "well equiped" group photo grallery that registered members can upload photos to. The gallery should include basic gallery features such as a view counter, to record how many people viewed a certain image. As well as the ability to comment on the photo.

I am a complete Drupal noob, this is my first Drupal project migrating over from WordPress because I believe Drupal has better flexibility and features as a CMS. I've created a view for our gallery, and am using the colorbox module for a stylish and professional presentation of the photos when clicked. I am also using the statistic module.

The road block I am at is that using the statistics module in partnership with the colorbox module image views are not being recorded. I believe this is because when you click on the image you don't actually navigate to the node, instead the image is pulled from the node and displayed in a colorbox modal. So, no matter the web traffic to the gallery and the photos being clicked or not, it always displays 0 views.

Is there a way to make it so when a image is clicked in the gallery and colorbox presents the image to the viewer it counts as a view?

The in-progress site I'm working on is [beta.semiphoto.org](http://beta.semiphoto.org) The gallery can be found [here](http://beta.semiphoto.org/?q=group-gallery). Please don't judge, I haven't addressed themeing and am still learning drupal. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot since colorbox calls the image directly and not through a node page to register the hit. Your going to have to custom code in a js script. when an image is clicked it would report back to the server via ajax to record that hit per image.

Answer (score 0):

For Downloads there's the [Download Count](https://www.drupal.org/project/download_count) module. But it Needs a Core Patch.

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... tracks downloads of private files attached to nodes via the core upload or contributed filefield modules for D6 and private core file fields for D7.